# Cannot change div text color or background color

Tags: html, css

This div is not responding to changes to color, background color, and border width. Why? I've never had this problem before.

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="classic-button-1.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="classic-button-1">
        Sign In
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.classic-button-1 {
background-color: "#eb7a34";
padding: 0.3em 1.2em;
border: 0.1em solid #eb7a34;
border-radius: 0.12em;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.2s;
}

.classic-button-1:hover {
color: "#eb7a34";
background-color: "#eb7a34";
}
```

Comment: no quotation marks for hex code. #eb7a34 is correct

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that the stylesheet href is correct.

Comment: remove " around the color

Comment: You're right. Why did I think hex color needed quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes around the hex value

```
.classic-button-1 {
    background-color: #eb7a34;
}

.classic-button-1:hover {
    color: #eb7a34;
    background-color: #eb7a34;
}
```